# Submit form with hyperlink + add extra value

Tags: jquery, forms

Inside form I have a list with different links I would like to use to submit the form.
Each link has different value that I would like to use on the next page. 
What would be the best approach?

1. Get form field values and use them as variables in URL address of the link

or

2. Use onclick event to insert link value to hidden field and submit the form

Here's the trimmed code:

```
<form action="Aktif.php" method="get">

        <select name="City" id="City" class="" type="text"><option      value="Tokyo"></option>
        </select>

        <input name="Date" class="" id=“datetimepicker1"    type="text">



        <li>
    <a href="Aktif.php?Actif=Fitness&City=&Date=>Fitness</a>

    </li>


    <input type="submit" class="" value="Find">
    </form>
```

Comment: You're effectively asking "which is better, GET or POST"?

Comment: Define "best approach"

Comment: This is not a good practice to submit a form using `get` method.

Comment: j08691 - best way to submit form with a link and add one extra value to results defined in this link.